# Check if number is prime during compilation in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, c-preprocessor, primes

I have a template class that takes an unsigned integer as template parameter, but I have to make sure that number is a prime. I can check it in the constructor, for instance, but it would be better to do it during compilation.

Here's the Assert template I'm using:

```
template <bool statement>
class Assert;

template <>
struct Assert<true> {};
```

I can simply create an object of this type in any piece of code which is going to be compiled, using my condition as parameter, and it won't compile if that condition is false. The problem is that I have to check if some number is prime. Let it be n.

I've came up with the idea of including a separate file "PrimeTest.h" and trying to divide n by each number from n-1 to 1 by including the same file from inside that file. That is how I use it:

```
#define SUSPECT n
#include "PrimeTest.h"
```

This is the "PrimeTest.h":

```
#ifdef SUSPECT

    #ifndef CURRENT
        #define CURRENT (SUSPECT-1)
    #endif // CURRENT

    #ifndef FINISHED

    #if CURRENT>100
        #define IS_PRIME
        #define FINISHED
    #else
        #if SUSPECT%CURRENT==0
            #define IS_NOT_PRIME
            #define FINISHED
        #else
            #define CURRENT (CURRENT-1)  // THAT DOES NOT WORK!!!
            #include "PrimeTest.h"
        #endif // SUSPECT % CURRENT != 0
    #endif

    #endif // FINISHED

#endif // SUSPECT
```

But here's the problem: I can't decrement CURRENT in any way I could come up with, including temporary values and #pragma push_macro directives.
Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Do you have access to any C++11 features?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual C++, and it does not support constexpr yet.
But that's fine, I've managed to cope with this using additional template structure.

Comment: Ayep, they are roughly equivalent.  If you only need small primes @CygnusX1's answer will do.  The `constexpr` answer I did below can be adapted for `template` based solutions if you need larger numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need preprocessor to compute something at compile-time.
Usually, when computation is needed, you use template metaprogramming (or `constexpr` functions as suggested by chris in his answer)

Via template metaprogramming you can solve the task as follows:

First you define a template which can check at compile time if the given value `N` is divisble by `D` or any value lower than `D` greater than 1.

```
template <int N, int D>
struct tmp {
    static const bool result = (N%D) && tmp<N,D-1>::result;
};

template <int N>
struct tmp<N,1> {
    static const bool result = true;
};
```

The value `tmp<N,D>::result` is `true` only when the numbers 2, 3, ... `D` do not divide `N`.

With the above tool at hand, creating `is_prime` compile-time checker is fairly easy:

```
template <int N>
struct is_prime {
    static const bool result = tmp<N,N-1>::result;
};
```

Now the compile-time value `is_prime<N>::result` is `true` when `N` is prime, and `false` otherwise. The value can be supplied to further templates, like the `Assert` of yours.

Comment: I rolled back the suggested `std::integral_constant` because (a) It is C++11 feature, while the above solution sticks to old C++. With C++11 the `constexpr` of chris is cleaner. (b) Because then the `is_prime<N>::result` does not exist, but I still refer to it in the following paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

C++11 `constexpr` version that should be able to check numbers up to roughly 1500 on any compiler that implements the suggested recursion depth limit:

```
constexpr bool is_prime_helper( std::size_t target, std::size_t check ) {
  return (check*check > target) ||
    (
      (target%(check+1) != 0)
      && (target%(check+5) != 0)
      && is_prime_helper( target, check+6 )
    );
}
constexpr bool is_prime( std::size_t target ) {
  return (target != 0) && (target !=1) &&
    ( ( target == 2 || target == 3 || target == 5 )
    || ((target%2 != 0) && (target%3 != 0) && (target%5)!=0 &&
    is_prime_helper( target, 6 )));
}
```

to improve this, we do some fun with a binary search tree:

```
#include <cstddef>

constexpr bool any_factors( std::size_t target, std::size_t start, std::size_t step) {
  return
      !(start*start*36 > target)
  &&
  (
    ( (step==1)
      && (
        (target%(start*6+1) == 0)
        || (target%(start*6+5) == 0)
      )
    )
    ||
    ( (step > 1)
      &&
      (
        any_factors( target, start, step/2 )
        || any_factors( target, start+step/2, step-step/2 )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

which we then use like this:

```
constexpr bool is_prime( std::size_t target ) {
  // handle 2, 3 and 5 explicitly:
  return 
    (target == 2 || target == 3 || target == 5)
  ||
    (
      target != 0
      && target != 1
      && target%2 != 0
      && target%3 != 0
      && target%5 != 0
      && !any_factors( target, 1, target/6 + 1 ) // can make that upper bound a bit tighter, but I don't care
    );
}
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "97:" << is_prime(97) << "\n";
  std::cout << "91:" << is_prime(91) << "\n";
}
```

which will recurse ~ `log_2(target/6)` times, which means that the recursion limit of `constexpr` expressions of 512 that C++11 standard requests that compilers implement as a minimum is no longer a problem.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/sbB4Qs), with debugging embedded.

This will work up to basically the limits of `std::size_t` on your system.  I've tested it with `111111113`.

This is insanely easier in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), as we no longer need one-line constexpr functions, but instead sane structure.  [See here](https://ideone.com/qIunvM).

```
constexpr bool any_factors( std::size_t target, std::size_t start, std::size_t step ) {
  if (start*start*36 > target)
  {
      return false;
  }
  if (step==1)
  {
    bool one_mod_6 = target%(start*6+1) == 0;
    bool five_mod_6 = target%(start*6+5) == 0;
    return one_mod_6 || five_mod_6;
  }

  bool first_half = any_factors(target, start, step/2);
  bool second_half = any_factors(target, start+ step/2, (step+1)/2);

  return first_half || second_half;  
}
```

Comment: Making 2, 3, and 5 work is easy as well. It just involves doing `target == 2 || target%2 != 0` (in brackets) instead. And 0 and 1 can be taken care of with `target >= 2`.

Comment: 1111111111111111111 took a minute, but it worked. I might be having too much fun with this.

Comment: @chris Ya, what I posted originally had some bugs in it.  The "binary tree" version should be working above, except for 0 and 1.. lemme go fix those.

Comment: @chris the next step would be to support arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: Heh, won't that be fun. I don't usually do this kind of thing, so it's somewhat intriguing.

Comment: is_prime(361) returns true but 361 = 19 x 19 is not a prime.

Comment: @tntxtnt Sorry, off-by-one error in my divide and conquer.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an amateur solution that is for positive numbers and done at compile time, but it can't go too far before it breaks due to a recursion limit. I suppose you could add a square root parameter that you calculate manually to allow it to go up to what it does now squared. It does take advantage of C++11's `constexpr` functions, though, to make the syntax a bit nicer to use without extra work. In any case, it might be a good start and I look forward to seeing answers that work better.

```
constexpr bool IsPrime(std::size_t N, std::size_t I = 2) {
    return (N !=  2 ? N%I : true) //make 2 prime and check divisibility if not 2
        && (N >= 2) //0 and 1 are not prime
        && (I >= N-1 ? true : IsPrime(N, I+1)); //stop when I is too big
}
```

You can even make that square root done for you. For this example, I'll make `IsPrime` into a helper so that `IsPrime` can only be called with `N`:

```
//basically does ceil(sqrt(N))
constexpr std::size_t Sqrt(std::size_t N, std::size_t I = 2) {
    return I*I >= N ? I : Sqrt(N, I+1);
}

//our old IsPrime function with no default arguments; works with sqrt now
constexpr bool IsPrimeHelper(std::size_t N, std::size_t sqrt, std::size_t I) {
    return (N != 2 ? N%I : true) 
        && (N >= 2) 
        && (I >= sqrt ? true : IsPrimeHelper(N, sqrt, I+1));
}

//our new prime function: this is the interface for the user
constexpr bool IsPrime(std::size_t N) {
    return IsPrimeHelper(N, Sqrt(N), 2);
}
```

For me, this new version works with the number 521 where the other failed. It even works with 9973. The new expected high should be about the square of the old. If you want to go further, you could even modify `IsPrimeHelper` to increment by 1 when `I` is 2 and by 2 when `I` is not 2. That would lead to a new high of about twice this one.

Comment: I would expect an `IsPrime` function to take a single argument. Why do you take two? Otherwise, great idea of using `constexpr`. I am still thinking in "old" C++....

Comment: @CygnusX1, It's just to reduce the number of entities you need to one. You could wrap it in something that only takes one and calls this with a second argument of 2 instead of defaulting it. You can still use this as `static_assert(IsPrime(11), "11 is not prime.");`.

Comment: @CygnusX1, I decided to add the square root idea in and in the process, made your helper :)

Comment: 512 is the suggested max recursive depth of a `constexpr`.  You can make your code twice as efficient by doing a step-size of 2 between primes (after 2), and another 50% by doing it in step-sizes of 6 (checking X+1 and X+5 only after the first 6 numbers).

Comment: @Yakk, I started to suggest that at the bottom after I implemented the square root idea :)

Answer (score 0):

For something portable to traditional C compilers:

```
// preprocessor-compatible macro telling if x is a prime at most 15-bit
#define PRIME15(x) (((x)>1)&(((x)<6)*42+545925250)>>((x)%30&31)&&((x)<49\
||(x)%7&&(x)%11&&(x)%13&&(x)%17&&(x)%19&&(x)%23&&(x)%29&&(x)%31&&(x)%37\
&&(x)%41&&(x)%43&&(x)%47&&((x)<2809||(x)%53&&(x)%59&&(x)%61&&(x)%67\
&&(x)%71&&(x)%73&&(x)%79&&(x)%83&&(x)%89&&(x)%97&&(x)%101&&(x)%103\
&&(x)%107&&(x)%109&&(x)%113&&(x)%127&&(x)%131&&(x)%137&&(x)%139&&(x)%149\
&&(x)%151&&(x)%157&&(x)%163&&(x)%167&&(x)%173&&(x)%179&&(x)<32761)))
```

- `(x)>1` because all primes are at least 2
- `(x)<6` because because we special-case the primes 2 3 5
- `42` is [also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_is_42) a bitmap of these special primes `(1<<2)+(1<<3)+(1<<5)`
- `545925250` is a bitmap for 1 7 11 13 17 19 23 29, for a swift test of divisibility by 2 3 5
- `>>((x)%30&31)` accesses said bitmaps for said swift test¹
- `(x)<49` (resp. `(x)<2809` and `(x)<32761`) because we want to tell 7=√49 (resp. 53=√2809 and 181=√32761) prime
- `(x)%7&..&&(x)%47` and `(x)%53&&..&&(x)%179` because we test divisibility
- `179` because the square of the next prime exceeds 15 bits.

If the macro is used to generate code, it's pretty efficient.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNb5wwEL3zK6a7ymrdZRPMl0P241a1PUSKoko9JDkQ8CZegY0MaVbK5rdvB7Bp6SGnIoH9Zp7Hbx6GbNlk2el0cQGV5pVWGa9rpZeZKqu0EY8FhzLNtIKGF4WQTyB2cABRQ4p8UXJIGyhV3QCNlo@icaY53wnJ4eb2@/UXGs0PBOZzfG4pmXWTdUw@h/4iCqPEj/zII9ttGz4LvFmAnFnHCZN753hswwwjOFBqxsCMNp70o2/ivsGB4Qfs3ulnoYmEhhkys5d/6SX9XpFJRaZIbJbEQxFmIswwmWFeGnxpcGLleVa3F9ga1BuSiW3OduXbVDD0O0QsufXGTCPLiiwrtpViG2GDY32BdeCzmBJCHGcqZFa85BzWdZMLdf68dYTE15kKOf@lRE7ekLIbXqVPYDYbUDBC0QixEaJ0BMPxSpQTJsSB9jjJZjeffHvROv0EvguBC5ELzAVKXQgDSGUOHR2EzDnPIdW8P4Xn93JCVs6UFzXHUlOutdIw@amVfFIu1FVal9jQ1cdV/5SbYCmZi92o/yUKPx4H6I0QHaFwhOIRav1n/0YYJR/pXqJoDxWjYBdi12qOWadZqqbXvbIJRoEfMrSoxu8S8Lusu5Z6d6zRX5VCR/5DaWt@5xjgHwLdeMMJQIF9wB42sEwSFyROcKu6H6pVR3l9FgWfLxb7ddBeBP5yfE9gsZDtisUGKly279fYDq7T5pmX@JvKUngVRQGZkjuhyyu4aTXfnRX5w2aDz/bA/VBNWtz1idtUPvXph56ALbjSrfCuSbvHO96aNy9agrdy3k@n3w)

---

¹ The `&31` is a hack to workaround a warning for negative `x`. No, replacing the first `&` with `&&1&` won't cut it for a certain compiler for an embedded CPU which, at maximum warning level, reports errors in constant expressions with a negative shift including in subexpressions that a short-circuit boolean requires to not evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this constexpr to check if small number `n < 51529` are prime at compile time :

```cpp
static constexpr auto is_prime_51529(const int n) {
    // will not be repeated 7 times
    return (n > 1) & ((n < 6) * 42 + 0x208A2882) >> n % 30 && (n < 49 || n % 7 && n % 11 && n % 13 && n % 17 && n % 19 && n % 23 && n % 29 && n % 31 && n % 37 && n % 41 && n % 43 && n % 47 && (n < 2809 || 53 && n % 59 && n % 61 && n % 67 && n % 71 && n % 73 && n % 79 && n % 83 && n % 89 && n % 97 && n % 101 && n % 103 && n % 107 && n % 109 && n % 113 && n % 127 && n % 131 && n % 137 && n % 139 && n % 149 && n % 151 && n % 157 && n % 163 && n % 167 && n % 173 && n % 179 && n % 181 && n % 191 && n % 193 && n % 197 && n % 199 && n % 211 && n % 223));
}
```